# How to create a parse.com pointer to a class other than user?

Tags: parse-platform

Looking at this post https://parse.com/questions/pointers-user-with-javascript, I can see how this creates a pointer back to _User, but what if I want to link to another class say "Collection"

I'm guessing I need to switch out `Parse.User.current()` but what is the format for the class?

Basically I want a one to many pointer created between the classes.

```
var Mapper = Parse.Object.extend("mapper");
var a_mapper = new Mapper();
a_mapper.set("userPointer", Parse.User.current());
a_mapper.save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as easy as assigning a parse object to a value on another object.

```
var OtherClass = Parse.Object.extend("otherClass");
var oc = new OtherClass();
a_mapper.set("otherPointer", oc);
a_mapper.save();
```

Comment: Sorry... not sure I 100% follow. Lets say my class is called "A" and I want the pointer created here called "connector" and for it to point to the class "B". How is that achieved? THanks for the support (AGAIN!) ;-)

Comment: just make an object of class A and assign an object of class B to the key 'connector'.